# Getting Movement with Google Cardboard in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I want to put a scene in Unity into virtual reality using Google Cardboard.

I used to be able to just drag a CardboardMain prefab into the scene, delete the main camera, use CardboardMain as the camera position, and CardboardHead to track where the user was looking.

After reading the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes) for the new updates, I thought I could drag a GVREditorEmulator and GVRControllerMain into the scene, and keep the normal camera.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the camera to follow my character with this new setup. (In this case, a rolling ball.)

If I change the position of the normal camera, it looks like it works fine in Unity, but as soon as I upload it to my phone, the user stays in the same place, while the ball rolls away. (The user can still control the ball's movements, but the camera/user doesn't follow the ball at all.)

I had thought that the [chase cam demo](https://developers.google.com/vr/elements/chase-cam) would be useful, but that's only for Daydream, and I'm using Cardboard.

[This trick](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/606) seemed to work for some people. I tried in on a previous version of Unity and a previous version of the SDK and it did not seem to work. I may just need to try it on this new version, but I'm worried about going into the released code and editing it, so I'd prefer answers that don't require this.

Is there any way I can get the user to move in a Google Cardboard scene in Unity when I upload it to my iPhone?

UPDATE:
It looks as though my main camera object is not moving, making me think that something is resetting it back to the center every time, lending some more credence to the "trick" earlier. I will now try "the trick" to see if it works.

UPDATE: It doesn't look like the lines listed in the "trick" are there anymore, and the ones that are similar in the new program don't even seem to be running. Still trying to figure out what continues to reset the main camera's position.

UPDATE: Just got a response back from Google on GitHub (or at least someone working on the SDK) that says `"You just need to make the node that follows the player a parent of the camera, not the same game object as the camera."` I'm not exactly sure what that means, so if someone could explain that, that would most likely solve my problem. If I figure it out on my own I'll post back here.

UPDATE: Zarko Ristic posted an answer that explained what this was, but unfortunately the tracking is still off. I found out how to get Google Cardboard to work with the old SDK and posted an answer on that. Still looking for ways to get the new SDK to follow a character properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change positioin of camera in cardboard application, position of MainCamera it always must be 0,0,0. But you can just simply made empty GameObject and make it parent of MainCamera. In Cardboard games actualy you can move parent of camera instead MainCamera directly.
Add script for tracking ball to MainCamera parent (GameObject).

Comment: To be more specific, create an empty game object, drag the main camera under the empty game object, delete the movement script off of the camera and put it on the empty game object. Then the player should move. (Also, thank you so much - it would have taken me so long to find this elsewhere.)

Comment: You're welcome. Note: If you want move camera directly, you can use GVR SDK 0.6, also you don't need check VR suported box in Player setings which gives you many more options. I think this is the best SDK for Cardboard applications (not for Daydream or other).

Comment: I may try this, as my script is still not quite working correctly. The camera is moving, but not quite moving to the spot I expected it to.

Comment: When using SDK 0.6, I keep on getting a linker error that "ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /.../Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)" so I don't think I can use that one. (EDIT may be related to this: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/518)

Comment: Thanks for the resource! I wish it did, unfortunately my issue with 0.6 is in XCode, not Unity or anything Andriod. Maybe I tried to use the Google Cardboard enabled mode when I shouldn't have though... Let me go check.

Comment: I just checked, and I did have that enabled, which the video explicitly says not to do. The next thing to check is whether or not that fixes the linker error.

Comment: It looks like that was one step of a multi-step solution which I will post as an answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm using Unity 2017.1 right now, and it is working just fine.

Comment: @ProQ, you saved me, have been looking for this for days

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer my question, but is a solution to the problem.

1. Do not use the newest version of the SDK. Use version 0.6
2. When building the app in Unity, do not select to have VR enabled under the build settings. (VR will still be enabled in the app.) (Credit: Zarko Ristic)
3. When putting the app onto your phone, if XCode prompts you to change any settings, you can ignore it.
4. In addition, disable bitcode under "Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode -> No" (Currently, this will not allow you to put your app onto the app store. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone has information on how to get it to run without doing this.)

Now your app should run on your phone correctly.